# High-Level JS library for interactive network graph?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, library, javascript, web-development

I want an interactive network graph for my web page. I've set up a db containing edges and nodes. I have JS functions getNode(id) and getEdge(id), which properly returns edges and nodes with their properties. I want this displayed graphically, but don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want to just pass the edge and node info, don't care much for style. Essentials: (directed) edges and nodes with labels, plus click events I can write my own methods for. Is there such a JS library?

Comment: standard library question: do you care about licensing?

Comment: i want to display it to users, license must allow that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript library [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) (BSD license), it contains some nice function to [present the data as an interactive network](http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[More examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js), a Javascript toolkit to speed up the development of graph visualization and interaction applications. It is free for open source projects.

*Disclaimer:* I work at Linkurious SAS.